# C# Monitor Programs Periodically Based on PID

Tags: c#, process, monitoring, pid

Thank you in advance for you ideas and input.

I would like to periodically check to see if a third party program is currently running on a user's system from my program. I am currently launching the program as follows in C#:

```
        String plinkConString = ""; // my connection string
        Process plink = Process.Start(utilityPath + @"\putty.exe", plinkConString);
        int plinkProcessId = plink.Id;
```

I launch the program and grab its pid in a Windows environment. As Putty/PLink may disconnect from its SSH server at some point and close, what is the best way to monitor how this process is doing in code?

Is there a better way to launch this program to monitor its success or failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether the process is still up and running you can check the `HasExited` property:

```
Process plink = Process.Start(utilityPath + @"\putty.exe", plinkConString);
....
bool isRunning = plink.HasExited;
```

The following code would check whether putty is running. It works also, if the program has been started by the user:

```
bool isRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("putty").Length > 0;
```

Comment: I believe this is what I am looking for. I will give it a try and report back. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Process.WaitForExit()` or `Process.WaitForExit(int)`, or use the `Process.Exited` event handler. You may also be interested in `Monitor` if you want any more complex behaviour than that.

Comment: Thx for the response. I will do some research on WaitForExit().